# Apache status inactive(dead) in my production

Tags: python-3.x, apache

From couple of month my production is works fine with apache.But now it restart manually daily.When check my apache status it shows inactive(dead).can you please help me how to solve this issue. But when i restart my apache it works again.

Comment: ● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─forking.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Su 2016-10-16 23:24:07 KRAT; 14min ago
  Process: 1953 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1947 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Comment: apache is not listem my response, i check with the command as "sudo netstat -lntp | grep 80"